# How do I find out which programs connect to the internet at startup?

Tags: internet, startup

My installed OS is Ubuntu 12.10, 64 bit, English, kernel version 3.5.0.21

Which commands must I issue at the terminal window to find out the names of programs that connect to the internet immediately after Ubuntu boots up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo netstat --inet -p` will show current active or listening connections with names of programs.

**Upd**

To view connections with LISTENING state netstat must be invoked with additional `-a` option: `sudo netstat --inet -pa`

Comment: @ ASten: Thanks for your reply. I shall try it and report back if there are problems.

Answer (score 3):

[NetHogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/) is a handy little tool which shows you what processes are utilizing your bandwidth. You can startup this application immediately after reboot and you would know which programs are connecting to the internet at startup.

**Step 1** : Install NetHogs with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install nethogs
```

**Step 2** : Once installed, you may run nethogs with the following command:

```
sudo nethogs <interface>
```

replace `<interface>` with `eth0`, `wlan0`, `ppp0` depending on what you use to connect to the internet. If you are not sure, then run `ifconfig` to know what are the available options for you.

You may quit the program by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: @ Aditya: Thanks for your reply. How do I install it? Detailed instructions are welcome as I am new to Linux and Ubuntu. Othen than installing NetHogs, can we verify which programs connect to the internet at startup using one of Ubuntu's native tools? (I am rather averse to installing software that is not part of Ubuntu's official repository.)

Comment: @ Aditya: Thanks for taking the time to give me a detailed reply.